# Permission error using systemctl with a Minecraft server service

Tags: minecraft, systemctl

I am trying to run a Minecraft server using `systemctl`. My `mcserver.service` is the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
User=camiel
Group=users
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx1G -jar /home/camiel/mc/server.jar nogui


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The directory for the server is /home/camiel/mc. When trying to start the service, it gives the following error seen through `sudo journalctl -xe`:

```
Feb 09 22:54:49 debian java[27867]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: eula.txt (Permission denied)
```

Does anyone know how I can change permissions so that the service can read/write to the folder the server is based in?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Without stack trace details, it is hard to see what is throwing the exception.

Here are a couple of suggestions:

- Try running the server from your account at the command line, if that fails, then there is something work with its configuration.
- Verify that `eula.txt` exists in `/home/camiel/mc`? If not, create it with the correct content.
- Do all your files (e.g., JARs, `system.properties`, `eula.txt`, etc.) belong to the same user and group? Use `cd /home/camiel/mc && ls -las` to ensure that the user and groups are consistent. If not use `chown -R camiel:users *` at the root of the server directory.
- With the above command, also check permission bits. Directories should be `drwxrwxr-x` (775) and files should be `-rw-rw-r--`(664).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `WorkingDirectory` statement inside `[Service]`.

You should place there `WorkingDirectory=/home/camiel/mc`.

Answer (score 0):

Eula.txt is an "End User License Agreement" file that will prevent the server from running unless you've changed it's value to true, which means you've agreed to the license in the process.

Edit the text file.

`nano /home/camiel/mc/eula.txt`

Change the value "eula=false" to "eula=true"

```
#By changing the setting below to TRUE you are indicating your agreement to our EULA (https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula).
#Thu Feb 11 10:13:37 GMT 2021
eula=true
```

Ctrl-o and Enter to write the file,
Ctrl-x to exit

start the service again.

```
systemctl start minecraft.service
```

I would recommend watching the server log file while the server is running to see a live status of errors.

```
tail -f /logs/latest.log
```

Comment: strange - looks like an easy to understand answer to me. eula.txt is a consent file specific to the minecraft server. it has to be changed for the server to run.

Comment: Excuse me - I see your point and I want to be a helpful member to the StackOverflow community.

Comment: Good style, taking feedback and acting on it. Please understand that I cannot vote up on this answer, simply because of me not knowing the technical topic enough.